# Convert MapInfo .TAB to Latitude and Longitude Points

Tags: mapinfo

I have been given MapInfo data with .TAB, .MAP, .ID and .DAT files and I am wanting to convert this information into latitude and longitude points.  The goal is to have a set of latitude and longitude points that I can use in an iPad app to create overlays.

I found an application that would load the MapInfo and generate png images suitable for viewing in Google Maps.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**Update**

@Darren Cope helped me find this to work:

ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" c:\temp\GeoJsonOutput C:\temp\myMapData.TAB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OGR](http://gdal.org/ogr/index.html) will read mapinfo files, and export to virtually any format you can imagine. You may want to try that first.

Comment: I downloaded FWTools 2.4.7 and used OpenEV_FW and I was able to load my files.  When I try to export them, all of the options seem to be an image format or another map format.  I do not see how to export as latitude and longitude points.

Comment: I'm assuming your features are points? You should be able to export to a .csv using OGR. You can do it from the command line if OpenEV_FW doesn't work.

Comment: On the command line you'd want something like: ogr2ogr -f csv -lco GEOMETRY=AS_XY output.csv input.tab

Comment: CSV output yielded lots of useful information but unfortunately not latitude and longitude.  However, after trying several different output formats I found that GeoJSON would output coordinates.